# Restoring javascript variables after linking to a pdf

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick

In javascript I want to link out to a pdf file and when the user returns with the back button, restore variables and do something with them. But on return, the whole page seems to be reloaded and all the js variables reset.

```
<a href="stuff.pdf" id="testit">Stuff</a>
...
$('#testit').click (function testit ()
  { g2 = 2; }
);
```

Is there any way to pass information across the link to the pdf? (And am I setting up the click handler correctly -- it does work.) Or is there some way to execute the link within js?

Yes, I am a js novice, but I have everything working except this issue.

Thanks. --David

Comment: when link is clicked a new http request is made and new page loaded, the previous info is lost. You can always open the link in a new tab, that way you keep both pages and the info

Comment: Would it work to open it in a new tab, via `<a href="stuff.pdf" target="_blank">`?

Comment: save those variables as cookies?